# Telegram api send an already uploaded photo

Tags: telegram

Telegram bot api supports sending an already uploaded photo. Does telegram api also support sending an already uploaded photo?

I looked at the api documentation but couldn't find any relevant method.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain `file_id` in response of `sendPhoto`, just use it as `photo` field like `chat_id`.

For instance:

```
callAPI("sendPhoto", [
    "chat_id": 109780439,
    "file_id": "AAAAAAXXX"
]
```

Comment: I don't see any sendphoto in telegram API. Can you post a link where you found it?

Comment: @apadana How did you upload photo?

Answer (score 1):

if you use this lib https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api, it's working code:

```
$chat_id = <chat_id>;
$token = <token>;
$bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\BotApi($token);

try {

    $bot->sendPhoto($chat_id, <file_id>, 'caption');

} catch (\TelegramBot\Api\Exception $e) {

    $e->getMessage();

}
```

if not, this is simple GET method:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<chat_id>&photo=<file_id>
```

more info [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question is regarding telegram api, not bot api which is different.